# Convert string to pygame.key

Tags: python, pygame

For my game I need to take a string, consisting of one character, and check, if a key with this character was pressed (I'm using pygame). 
For example, if the string was 'a', I would need to have something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_a:
   [...]
```

I can just make a lot of `if` statements for each key, but I hope there's a faster way

[Edit] I tried to use the `ord` function:

```
[...]
  if event.key == ord(key): #key is my string's name
[...]
```

but now, for some reason, no matter I press w or s, event.key is the same number

Comment: Can you give an example of the if statement you would use for key `A`, for example?  Or are you stuck there?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ord(c)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to get the ordinary number, that represents a character. e.g:

```py
ch = 'a'

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == ord(ch):
                # [...]
```

But note, `if event.unicode == ch:`, would do the same.